# How to expand floating divs to take up the space left by the dynamically removed divs?

Tags: jquery, css, html, internet-explorer-6

This is basically for a comparison page where you can compare 2-5 products.

I need to know if I have 5 floating divs in a main div. All 5 divs are dynamically created. When a user selects 5 products for comparison then the main is is filled with 5 divs. But in case the user selects only 2 products for comparison. The 2 divs do not fill space and only cover up the width for the 2 divs. I want them to fill up the main container.

I hope I make sense. Let me know in case you need the code for reference.

JavaScript and jQuery can be used.

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support? IE7?

Comment: Lol - came in here thinking we were talking about float vs int/fixed point division :)

Comment: I need it to work and should support browser over IE6. If it can be achieved with js I am open to it. :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to point out that you could use percent, but this wouldn't work either. If you can set classnames on the serverside (e.g. php-script which knows how many columns should be shown), you could define a

```
.twoColumnLayout{
  width:50%;
}
```

and a

```
.threeColumnLayout{
  width:33%;
}
```

...

But this would be easier if you'd use javascript (with jQuery for example), where you could determine how many columsn there are and then setting the with of each column dynamically within the page.

Comment: Boo If you have an example of the jquery which could do this, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<div>").insertAfter(element).css("width", 99 / countColumns + "%")
```

The 99 is there (not 100) because some browsers don't like 100% width with scrollbars and actually wrap the content (you can also set overflow: hidden).

My jQuery-fu is kind of rusty and I'm away from my development rig, but the above sample should work..... :p

Comment: Hi Can you please get me an example as I am not a programmer I might not be able to use this. Thanks for your help Art... I really appreciate it.